# mysql_init(NULL) segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, c, segmentation-fault

I have the following function:

```
int get_tcounter(char *meterType, int *error) {
    MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    get_connection(conn, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB); 

    MYSQL_STMT *stmt = mysql_stmt_init(conn);
    if (!stmt) {
        log_to_console("Init stmt failed: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    prepare_stmt(conn, stmt, GET_TCOUNTER_SQL);

    MYSQL_BIND param[1], res[1];
    memset(param, 0, sizeof(param));
    memset(res, 0, sizeof(res));

    char *paramBuff;
    int tcBuff;
    my_bool isNullParam[] = {0}, isNullRes[] = {0};

    paramBuff = meterType;

    bind_string_param(&param[0], strlen(meterType), paramBuff, &isNullParam[0], (unsigned long *) 0);
    bind_result(&res[0], MYSQL_TYPE_LONG, (char *) &tcBuff, &isNullRes[0], (unsigned long *) 0);

    execute_statement(stmt, param, res);

    *error = TRUE;
    int ret = 0;
    if (!mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt)) {
        ret = tcBuff;
        *error = FALSE;
    }

    mysql_stmt_close(stmt);
    mysql_close(conn);

    return ret;
}
```

First time I execute the function all is working as expected, but the second time around, `mysql_init` line throws Segmentation Fault.

Here's the core dump:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fe23ee22f08 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) down
Bottom (innermost) frame selected; you cannot go down.
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007fe23ee24536 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#2  0x00007fe23ee270b5 in malloc () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#3  0x00007fe23fa951d2 in my_malloc () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
(gdb) up
#4  0x00007fe23fa788df in mysql_init () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
(gdb) up
#5  0x0000000000403ed4 in get_tcounter (meterType=0x24bcbd0 "M-9669-8", error=0x7fff6b57a8a8) at database/data_access.c:284
284     MYSQL *conn = mysql_init(NULL);
```

The strange thing is that in first call `conn` is 0x0 before init, but the second time it's some arbitrary 0x7fff... address.

Tied assigning NULL to conn and freeing conn before init to no avail.

Comment: In multi-threaded environments you are supposed to call [`mysql_library_init`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-library-init.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance this is memory corruption that sets up some bad state in MySQL. Try running this under Valgrind to see if there is a double `free` or invalid access of some kind.

Answer (score -1):

Don't link debug library(libmysqld.lib), i test it on win10+mysql5.6 5.7+vs2017, mysql_init always return NULL or crash. You should link release library(libmysql.lib).

Comment: The question appears to be about Linux, so a Windows solution is not much use here, I think.